# When to use semicolons and brackets

Tags: javascript

I am still having a hard time figuring out when to use semicolons ; and brackets {}. Anyone break it down for me? This I think is the hardest part of coding. Thanks!

Comment: thanks to all who responded and up me))))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semicolons should be used to terminate statements. Brackets should be used to group more than one statements in a code block, for example when writing `if` conditions, loops (`for`, `while`) or functions. Brackets are also used when creating objects.

Example:

```
var foo = 'bar';
if (foo == 'bar') {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        alert('Hello ' + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple answer. I would suggest always use proper punctuations even if the block just contains only one statement. to me `if(condition){statement();}` is preferred over `if (condition)statement()`

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces `{}` are for code blocks which can contain multiple to single code statements. Where as a semicolon `;` is to delineate or tell the compiler where a particular line of code ends.

You might want to go through [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp) W3 School page on JavaScript Statements.

Excerpt from the page:

> Semicolon separates JavaScript statements.
>
> [...]
>
> JavaScript statements can be grouped together in blocks.
>
> Blocks start with a left curly bracket, and end with a right curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons to separate several instructions in a single line

```
inst1; inst2; inst3;
```

Brackets when you have more than one line of code in conditionals or loops

```
if (condition) {
  line1
  line2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you complete a **statement** (a statement can be **declaration, function call, any expression** e.g assignment expression) then you should add `;`  For example:

```
var i = 10;  // declaration 
fun(10); // calling a function 
i = j + 3 && 20;  // an expression
```

You should use `{` `}` for you wants to make a **block of statements** generally when you defines **function, while, for, if, switch-case** etc.

Example:

(1)

```
if(a = b){
  fun(2);  // call a function 
  a = a + b;
}
```

(2)

```
while(1){
  statement-1; 
  statement-2; 
}
```

(3) function:

```
function f(var){
    statement-1; 
    statement-2; 
}
```

Special more cases:

You need `;` after `}` in a for dict and function:

```
var foo = function() {
    statement-1; 
};  // not your need both `;` and `}`
```

This value both function definition and assignment expression

objects:

```
var obj = {
  a : 1,
  b: 2,
};  // not you uses both `;` and `}`
```